# In which timezone the usage limit of GMail API for a day is counted?

Tags: timezone, gmail-api, quota

I have found the daily usage quota of GMail API [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota). However, I want to know the timezone in which the day is taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it on [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) on API's and Services with the API you want to check.

In Gmail API:

[image: Gmail quota]